# Dovecot IMAP and SMTP suddenly not available

Tags: email, server, smtp, imap, dovecot

Hello Community and first things First:

```
    dovecot --version
    2.2.9
    dovecot -n
    # 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
    # OS: Linux 3.13.0-042stab125.5 x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
    auth_mechanisms = plain login
    dict {
      sqlquota = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf
    }
    listen = *,[::]
    log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
    login_log_format_elements = user=<%u> method=%m rip=%r lip=%l mpid=%e %c %k
    mail_fsync = always
    mail_home = /var/vmail/%d/%n
    mail_location = maildir:~/
    mail_nfs_index = yes
    mail_nfs_storage = yes
    mail_plugins = quota acl
vmanagesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
    mmap_disable = yes
    namespace {
      list = yes
      location = maildir:%%h/:INDEXPVT=~/Shared/%%u
      prefix = Shared/%%u/
      separator = /
      subscriptions = yes
      type = shared
    }
    namespace inbox {
      inbox = yes
      location =
      mailbox Archiv {
        special_use = \Archive
      }
      mailbox Archive {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Archive
      }
      mailbox Archives {
        special_use = \Archive
      }
      mailbox "Deleted Messages" {
        special_use = \Trash
      }
      mailbox Drafts {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Drafts
      }
      mailbox Entwürfe {
        special_use = \Drafts
      }
      mailbox "Gelöschte Objekte" {
        special_use = \Trash
      }
      mailbox Gesendet {
        special_use = \Sent
      }
      mailbox Junk {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Junk
      }
      mailbox Papierkorb {
        special_use = \Trash
      }
      mailbox Sent {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Sent
      }
      mailbox "Sent Messages" {
        special_use = \Sent
      }
      mailbox Trash {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Trash
      }
      prefix =
      separator = /
    }
    passdb {
      args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
      driver = sql
    }
    plugin {
      acl = vfile
      acl_anyone = allow
      acl_shared_dict = file:/var/vmail/shared-mailboxes.db
      quota = dict:User quota::proxy::sqlquota
      quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+100%%
      sieve = /var/vmail/sieve/%u.sieve
      sieve_after = /var/vmail/sieve/global.sieve
      sieve_max_script_size = 1M
      sieve_quota_max_scripts = 0
      sieve_quota_max_storage = 0
    }
    protocols = imap sieve lmtp pop3
    service auth {
      unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth_dovecot {
        group = postfix
        mode = 0660
        user = postfix
      }
      unix_listener auth-master {
        mode = 0600
        user = vmail
      }
      unix_listener auth-userdb {
        mode = 0600
        user = vmail
      }
      user = root
    }
    service dict {
      unix_listener dict {
        group = vmail
        mode = 0660
        user = vmail
      }
    }
    service lmtp {
      unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
        group = postfix
        mode = 0600
        user = postfix
      }
      user = vmail
    }
    service managesieve-login {
      inet_listener sieve {
        port = 4190
      }
      process_min_avail = 2
      service_count = 1
      vsz_limit = 128 M
    }
    service managesieve {
      process_limit = 256
    }
    ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/mail/mail.crt
    ssl_cipher_list =     EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECD    H:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5    :!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-    SHA:AES128-SHA
    ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
    ssl_key = </etc/ssl/mail/mail.key
    ssl_protocols = !SSLv3 !SSLv2
    userdb {
      args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
      driver = sql
    }
    protocol imap {
      mail_plugins = quota imap_quota imap_acl acl
    }
    protocol lmtp {
      auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
      mail_plugins = quota sieve acl
      postmaster_address = postmaster@domain1.com
    }
    protocol sieve {
      managesieve_logout_format = bytes=%i/%o
    }
    remote 127.0.0.1 {
      disable_plaintext_auth = no
    }
```

Mail.err

```
Nov 13 23:59:06 webdev dovecot: auth: Error: PLAIN(account@domain2.com, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,<y869CoDETEST4dHk>): Request 29154.1 timed out after 150 secs, state=1
```

Mail.log

```
Nov 13 23:27:54 webdev dovecot: auth: Error: LOGIN(account@domain1.com,IP.IP.IP.IP,<oN4ly+TestDZ6dHk>): Request 28118.1 timed out after 150 secs, state=1
Nov 13 23:27:57 webdev dovecot: auth: Error: PLAIN( account@domain2.com,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,<FAxKe+JaatES7tHk>): Request 28120.1 timed out after 150 secs, state=1
Nov 13 23:28:24 webdev dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Inactivity during authentication (disconnected while authenticating, waited 180 secs): user=<>, method=LOGIN, rip=ClientIP, lip=ServerIP, TLS: Disconnected, TLSv1.2  with cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits) 
[...]
Nov 13 23:47:15 webdev dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=84.119.151.17, lip=62.75.185.32
```

I did not change anything on my client nor serverside setup and i suddenly could not reach the Mailserver anymore. Obviously I can reach the Server using SSH or HTTP.

I hope I provided all infos you need to help me in this situation. And am grateful for every hint to solve this as I dont even have a clue what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are talking about a timeout on the authentication, and the config shows that the authentication is using a MySQL database. For this reason I would check if the MySQL process is still up, or restart the service (if it's running as a service, which is probably the case).